# AIX Unix - How to Find and Remove files created between date period, with starting and ending characters?

Tags: find, wildcards, aix, search

I'm using IBM AIX Unix and it's limited with command option. I want to implement below filter criteria using find and mtime (which works) option. I would like to remove the files listed with below filter condition.

- files starting with number [0-9]
- ending with ".dat"
- and duration is between 1st Aug 2018 -15th Oct 2018

I was trying with find command but it didn't help much.

```
 find /mydirectory -type f -mtime -45 -mtime +5
```

Comment: Are relative dates ok, as you've started with? They depend on you running the command on a particular day.

Answer (score 2):

That `find` command looks for *things that are files* AND *things last modified less than 45 days ago* AND *things last modified more than 5 days ago*. (The "AND" restricts the dataset, not enlarges it. Read it as "that are also" if you prefer.)

Assuming you've matched your absolute date range, you now just need to add a clause that completes the set of criteria you've specified:

```
find /mydirectory -type f -mtime -45 -mtime +5 -name '[0-9]*' -name '*.dat'
```

Optimising a little, these two naming criteria

> - files starting with digit [0-9]
> - ending with ".dat"

can be merged into a single statement:

- files matching the glob ("shell wildcard pattern") `[0-9]*.dat`

Finally, you need a "*remove the matching files*" action, which we can implement with `rm -f`, and this then leads us to your required solution.

```
find /mydirectory -type f -mtime -45 -mtime +5 -name '[0-9]*.dat' -exec echo rm -f {} \;
```

*Remember to remove `echo` from that command when you see it's selecting files as you expect, so that the `rm` will be actioned rather than just printed*.

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are fixed, meaning you want to delete files with modification dates within that range regardless of *when* you run the command, then you could use [`touch` command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds5/touch.htm) to create reference files and [`find`'s](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_72/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/find.htm) `-newer` predicate to limit the results:

```
touch -t 201807312359.59 /tmp/oldest-file
touch -t 201810152359.59 /tmp/newest-file
find /mydirectory -type f -newer /tmp/oldest-file ! -newer /tmp/newest-file -name '[0-9]*.dat' -exec rm {} \;
```